# Alternatives to DBCC PAGE for working with page numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Are there any management views or functions or procedures that can resolve page numbers to object id's?  Everything I'm finding says to use `DBCC PAGE`, but I don't have the requisite permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations` if you're on SQL Server 2012 or greater.

For example, this will give you information about tempdb -- the number two passed in is database id.

`SELECT *
    FROM sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations(2, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED') AS dddpa;`

Comment: And the page id equivalent to what I'd be using with DBCC PAGE is allocated_page_page_id, right?

Comment: Yep, you got it.

Comment: Oh my... how typical of MS.  They have the very promising "page_free_space_percent" column in the output except that it only produces a non-null return for blobs and heaps.  It's as bad as the relatively new string splitter function that doesn't return the ordinal position of the returned elements.

Comment: @JeffModen as usual, it's almost useful.